# Is there a way to get iTunes to transfer my apps on an offline machine?

Tags: itunes, ipad

My Music collection is all my own and stored on a PC which doesn't connect to the internet. this has been fine for most cases however recently i've been needing to get a hold of a word processor and learned about Pages, problem is that it appears that the only way to get documents on and off my iPad [is to use iTunes](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH3567?locale=en_US).

As my PC is offline so when i connect my iPad to sync stuff like movie, music and images i get the a message saying it can't transfer my apps which is understandable as i can't sign into my apple account.

i could install itunes on my laptop but the documents i want to sync are on my offline PC for when i work on there (ipad work would be for when i don't have access like if i'm in the car for a 2 hour trip) and it's a pain keeping 2 sets up to date, not to mention as i saw in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TqZGVmVJTE) i can only sync with one itunes (to which my laptop doesn't have the space for my music and ripped movies)

So I am wondering if there is a way to transfer my apps from my iPad to iTunes on my offline PC? (ie. installing and loging into itunes on my laptop then copying something from my laptop to my PC to trick itunes on my PC that i did sign in)

Comment: @Buscar웃SD i'm not sure what *"tta"* means but yeh my PC stays offline and the only way i access the inetrnet is via wireless on my laptop (my PC has no wireless capabilities). i get files onto my PC it via USB but as i mentioned the laptop i use to connect to the internet isn't big enough for my collection (it has ~80 GB, my PC's music/movie collection is about ~900 GB)

Comment: I am confused with your question,. You have a PC and a iPad and a Laptop? PC is not connected to any network (even internal one). But you want to use Pages documents on the PC.

Comment: Now you want to transfer the 900 GB from PC to where? Does that laptop (presumably MacBook) has a ethernet plug ?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD when i connect my ipad to my PC it complains it can transfer my apps during the sync most likely because i can't log into my apple account because it's offline. i had a feeling someone would ask *"if i was able to install itunes on my offline pc then i must have downloaded it from somewhere, then why don't i install itunes there"* but i can't because i can't have it sync with 2 different itunes as shown in the video and i can't just move my collection to my laptop because it's too large

Comment: OK, simple question does the PC has a Ethernet plug (it looks like a phone plug but larger). Does the Laptop has a Ethernet plug? What kind of laptop is it?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD Both PC and Laptop have those plugs but because of location i can not use a Ethernet cable, the laptop connects to the internet via wireless. both the PC and Laptop are Windows 7 but i didn't think that would matter because i assume itunes is the same reagrdless

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer from iPad to Laptop using Internet and iTunes.

Now use a **cross-over** Ethernet cable, and transfer from Laptop to PC.

There is no Internet involved here, just the cable.

How to use **cross over cable** set up.

http://smallbusiness.chron.com/connect-laptop-pc-via-ethernet-cable-56523.html

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/connect-two-computers-crossover-cable#1TC=windows-7

All above also works in reverse.

Get the crossover ethernet cable.

[http://www.amazon.com/Belkin-CAT5E-Crossover-Cable-feet-Red/dp/B000067RFT](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000067RFT)

Comment: so after I link up the laptop and PC then what? will iTunes on my PC automatically detect iTunes on my laptop and get the apps from it?

Comment: I think this answer is a way to connect your offline PC to the internet using nothing else but your online Laptop and an ethernet cable. Then you'll be able to sign in from iTunes on your Desktop computer.